# how to use multiple models in one view django?

Tags: python, django

Actually guys, i don't know if thats correct, but someone told me that django is limitless, so...

**in views.py**

```
class SelfieList(ListView):
    template_name = "SelfieList.html"
    model = Selfie, Outfit
```

Can that be posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Listview accepts only one model and performs a `model.objects.all()` in `self.get_queryset()` method. One thing you can do is to inherit from `View` and then `pass querysets of multiple models as context data`